# Mongodb Realm custom JWT auth causes empty custom user data

Tags: mongodb, jwt, realm

I'm working on an app that currently uses email/password auth provided by MongoDB Realm. I'm thinking of switching to using the custom JWT auth for various reasons. I'm quite extensively using the custom user data to store all sorts of things. When I switch from email/password to custom JWT the login works, but the custom user data is empty...

This works fine:

```js
        const jwt = await axios.post("https://MYAPI.COM/login", {
          user: email.value,
          password: password.value,
        });
        console.log(`jwt: ${JSON.stringify(jwt.data)}`);
        const credentials = Realm.Credentials.emailPassword(
          email.value,
          password.value
        );
        // const credentials = Realm.Credentials.jwt(jwt.data);
        console.log("logging in");
        const user = await realm.logIn(credentials);
        await user.refreshCustomData();
        const customUserData = await user.refreshCustomData()
        console.log(`Logged in as ${JSON.stringify(user)}`);
        console.log(`customUserData: ${JSON.stringify(customUserData)}`);
```

When I uncomment the line changing the credentials the custom user data is empty

Comment: I'm running into a similar situation with CustomFunction Authentication. I'll post back if I figure something out

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar problem using Custom Function for authentication.
I was mapping the userId incorrectly -
custom user data is based on the ID of the authenticated user, please make sure that the user ID is mapped correctly in the corresponding collection.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/users/enable-custom-user-data/